# i am new to writing angularjs directives how to add style to directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was using the `<style>` tag in the template.

Is this the best way or are there any other better ways

the css code is around 20 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way, but it would be better to use a css class. Specify the styles in a class within a stylesheet and then specify that class with a `class` attribute on the appropriate html tag(s) within the directive.

Something like this in a stylesheet (a file with the .css extension):

```
.whiteTextOnBlack { 
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

And then refer to that class like this within the directive template:

```
<p class="whiteTextOnBlack">I'm text that has been styled</p>
```